# Pass pipeline as an argument to bash script and run it

Tags: bash, shell, pipeline

Is it possible to run something like this:

```bash
parent-script.sh "child-script1.sh | child-script2.sh"
```

and execute $1 inside the parent-script.sh?

```bash
...
CMD=$1
...
$CMD
```

Comment: yes, but it is insecure, and you have to be very careful with quoting. The syntax is `eval ...`

Comment: ... and there is almost surely a better way to solve the underlying problem, whatever that might be.

Comment: `eval "$CMD"` may do what you want, but see [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).  Also note that ALL_UPPERCASE names (like `CMD`) are unsafe in general.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).

Comment: Also see [Should I save my scripts with the .sh extension?](https://askubuntu.com/q/503127).

Comment: 'eval' is a common misspelling of 'evil'. If eval is the answer, surely you are asking the wrong question. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: Assigning the command-line pipeline to a variable in the script is very bad.  It would be better to simply chose to execute "eval $1".  Otherwise, any escaped quotations would be removed and change the interpretation of the pipeline.